# AC Blower cycles off and on after 60 seconds?

Tags: hvac

I have an older Goodman central air unit. Furnace ran fantastic all winter. Fired up Ac, now the blower runs for 60 seconds and shuts off. Repeatedly. The compressor outside never shuts off. There is nothing freezing and it happens immediately,  as soon as I turn it on.  If I go back to furnace it runs just fine again. What should i be looking at to determine the cause?

Comment: Is this the indoor blower in the furnace, or the condenser fan for the air conditioner? Also, what model is the furnace?

Comment: Is the 60 seconds very specific or does it mean something close to a minute?  I.e. if you time it is it exactly 60 seconds every time?  Can you predict down to the second when the blower will go off everytime? or does it run for ‘somewhere around a minute’?  Also 2 questions just to confirm: the same thermostat operates heating and cooling? The thermostat wasn’t upgraded since last cooling season?

Comment: The problem appears to be with the blower. When i said compressor i meant condenser.  Furnace is a Goodman.

Comment: about 47 - 60 seconds is a more accurate estimate.  It did seem to randomly start running longer yesterday for some odd reason. I changed nothing.   To answer your two questions,  1. Yes same thermostat. 2. No, no upgrades.